# Fetch results based on drop down values in a form

Tags: python, django, search, filter

I am new to Django/Python and creating a self-learning project

I have a page with 5 different input select fields

1. brand 2. Model 3. Mileage 4. Price_Range 6.Year_of_Make

I have a model called Products with all the fields above.

My html has following fields

```
    <div class="form-group">
          <select class="form-control from-control-sm" id="body" name="bodystyle" value="{{ request.Get.bodystyle }}">
               <option>Body</option>
               <option>Compact</option>
               <option>Convertible</option>
               <option>Coupe</option>
               <option>Off-road</option>
               <option>Sedan</option>
          </select>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
          <select class="form-control" id="product_make" name="product_make" value="{{ request.Get.product_make }}">
               <option>Ford</option>
               <option>Tata</option>
               <option>Hyundai</option>
               <option>Kia</option>
               <option>Honda</option>
               <option>Skoda</option>
          </select>
   </div>
```

Here is my views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from products.models import Products
from django.db.models import Q
# Create your views here.

def select(request):
    q1 = request.GET.get('product_make')
    q2 = request.GET.get('model_name')
    q3 = request.GET.get('bodystyle')


    cars = Products.object.filter(Q(bodystyle__icontains=q3)&Q(product_make__icontains=q1)&Q(model_name__icontains=q2))

    return render(request, 'search/search.html', {'cars': cars})
```

When I click on the Enter Button:

The URL changes to
http://127.0.0.1:8000/select/?bodystyle=Sedan&product_make=Ford
but no result is displayed.

My urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.contrib import admin
from pages.views import home_view
from search.views import search
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static


urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', home_view, name='home'),
    url(r'^home/', home_view, name='home'),
    url(r'^search/', search, name='search'),
    url(r'^select/', search, name='select'),
    url('ajax/home_view/',home_view, name='ajax_load_models'),
    ]+ static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

I want {% for item in cars %} to be populated so I can show results.

Answer (score 0):

This piece of code got my code working

```
total = s.count()
 s= s[0:total]
 cars = s.execute()
```